# Exporting Prestashop 1.6 products with description to CSV file

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to export my products from Prestashp 1.6.1.10 to CSV file but exported file does not have description column. Also in admin dashboard there is no option to choose what kind of parameters I want to export. Anyone know how to export product including description?